# tableau ONLINE: need a way to UNCHECK the "ALL" on all dashboard filters with a single click

Tags: tableau-api

tableau ONLINE: need a way to UNCHECK the "ALL" on all dashboard filters with a single click. Selecting - and then deselecting - "ALL" (in each filter) is NOT an option. Only clearing visualization filters with a CLEAR button that points to a another sheet with a dashboard action is NOT what I need -- as that does NOT uncheck the filters

tried clear button described above. Also tried SETS which also does not uncheck filters. Also tried parameters which works for ALL and NONE, but unable to multi-select other values - which I need to be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a multi-select dropdown filter.

### A few options:

- Unselect *ALL* in your filter before publishing, then publish. This will default your dashboard to show only values you selected whenever the dashboard is refreshed, but users will still be able to change and edit filter values.
- Remove the *Show 'ALL' Value* option in your "Customize Filter" settings.

*Since this question is tagged `tableau-api`*

- You can pass your filter selections through a URL string:

  - [Understanding Tableau URL Structure](https://anyonconsulting.com/business_intelligence/how-to-filter-a-tableau-report-using-the-url/)
  - [Passing Parameters via URL](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/HowTo/how-to-set-workbook-parameter-value-in-view-url-and-in-rest-api-call)